# reader.GetDateTime(null)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on an application that will read from a stored procedure and put into the worksheet. My problem is that when I  run into a null it isn't handled in the code.

```
               while (reader.Read())
               {

                   ws.Cells[i, 1] = reader.GetString(0);
                   ws.Cells[i, 2] = reader.GetString(1);
                   ws.Cells[i, 3] = reader.GetString(2);
                   ws.Cells[i, 4] = reader.GetString(3);
                   ws.Cells[i, 5] = reader.GetString(4);
                   ws.Cells[i, 6] = reader.GetString(5);
                   ws.Cells[i, 7] = reader.GetDecimal(6);
                   ws.Cells[i, 8] = reader.GetDateTime(7);
                   ws.Cells[i, 9] = reader.GetDecimal(8);
                   ws.Cells[i, 10] = reader.GetDecimal(9);
                   ws.Cells[i, 11] = reader.GetDecimal(10);
                   ws.Cells[i, 12] = reader.GetDecimal(11);
                   ws.Cells[i, 13] = reader.GetDateTime(12);
                   ws.Cells[i, 13] = reader.GetDateTime(13);
                   i++;
               }
               reader.Close();
```

if someone could explain how to handle this so that we just leave the cell null; thanks!!

Comment: why don't you use an ORM and take the value from the DTO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reader.IsDBNull` to check if a value is null and write conditional logic in your code.

```
if (reader.IsDBNull(12)) {
    ws.Cells[i, 13] = "";
} else {
    ws.Cells[i, 13] = reader.GetDateTime(12);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reader.IsDBNull(int)` to check if a field is null before attempting to read a value from it.

For example

```
ws.Cells[i, 1] = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "Default value when null" : reader.GetString(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create an extension method to do this.

Something like:

```
static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? TryGetDateTime(this DataTableReader reader, int ordinal)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
ws.Cells[i, 1] = reader.TryGetDateTime(1);
```

To handle *any* data type, you could try using generics:

```
public static T TryGetValue<T>(this DataTableReader reader, int ordinal)
{
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? default(T) : reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
ws.Cells[i, 1] = reader.TryGetValue<DateTime?>(1);
```

Comment: Good proposal. Just one thing : exception handling could be better (safer), check for DBNull instead. And the extension method could be enhanced using generics to handle other types.

Comment: Will this work even though they all aren't DateTime?

Comment: Yeah I agree now with the check for DBNull. I'll update the code. The main idea of the proposal which I forgot to add was that to keep the code clean and readable!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ws.Cells[i, 1] = reader.IsDbNull(0) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
```